# Aside from Spider-Man, who else has had the Captain Universe powers?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I was wondering if there were any other significant instances of heroes or simply other sentient beings being granted the Captain Universe powers for an extended period of time in the Marvel Universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently lot of [heroes and other sentient beings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Universe#Hosts), including:

- Doctor Strange (merged with Commander Arcturus Rann)
- [Hulk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Universe:_Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_1)
- [Daredevil](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Universe:_Daredevil_-_The_Man_Without_Fear!_Vol_1_1)
- [X-23](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Universe:_X-23_Vol_1_1)
- [Invisible Woman](https://www.comixology.com/Captain-Universe-Invisible-Woman-1/digital-comic/505516)
- [Silver Surfer](https://comicstore.marvel.com/Captain-Universe-Silver-Surfer-1/digital-comic/1657)
- Juggernaut
- Deadpool
- [Miles Morales](https://www.cbr.com/spider-geddon-miles-morales-captain-universe/)

There's also a (long) entry about Captain Universe on [marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/captain-universe).

Comment: Wait...wouldn't Silver Surfer gaining more cosmic power be somewhat redundant? How did it effect him?

Comment: Also several characters in Micronauts, the series that introduced Captain Universe. The first was, IIRC, the dad of a young boy whom the Micronauts befriend in the first story arc.